# Route by path in front web applications using nginx or kukbernetes ingress

Tags: javascript, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Suppose I own a domain name xxx.yyy.com, but I doesn't own any subdomain name (*.xxx.yyy.com) of it.

So I have to route each HTTP request to its corresponding service by `path`. For example, routing xxx.yyy.com/app1/ to service `app1` and xxx.yyy.com/app2/ to service `app2`.

I config my kubernestes resources as below:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: xxx.yyy.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/app1"
            backend:
              service:
                name: app1
                port:
                  number: 8000
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/app2"
            backend:
              service:
                name: app2
                port:
                  number: 8000
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  selector:
    app: app1
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app2
spec:
  selector:
    app: app2
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
```

This works in most of the cases, except in front webapps.

In a front webapp's HTML and javascript code, we refer its assets (images, HTTP APIs) on the backend server by root path ("/") , as if it is deployed on its own server.

For example in the javascript code of `app1` , we call `fetch('/api/getUsers')` instead of `fetch('/app1/api/getUsers')`, so the ingress failed to route `/api/getUsers` to service `app1`.

I know it can be solved easily by routing request by `host` not by `path`. But I don't have the permission to create subdomains.

So how can this scenario of front webapps be solved by routing by `path` ingress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Web application is available to the Browser beneath a certain path, the front end requests need to target that path. You can achieve this by

- using only relative path names like `api/guestUsers` instead of `/api/guestUsers`
- or prefixing every query url with that path, like `/app1/img/logo.png`.

The second way is supported by, for example by:

- Webpack: [`publicPath: "/app1"`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/)
- React Router: [`<BrowserRouter basename="/app1"/>`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#browserrouter)
- Angular: [`<base href="/app1"/>`](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag)

This setting could be dynamicly filled with a server variable or even [set automatically](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#automatic-publicpath) to the location of the entry point.

Comment: thanks. but I don't own the frontend web app. is there any way not by changing the frontend web app code， only changing kubernetes or nginx config code？

Comment: Say both app1 and app2 fetch a `/logo.png` and display it. You could serve one app at `/app1/...` and the other at`/app2/...` but the one logo you provide at `/logo.png` will show up in both apps. Ok, you could do the [routing based on the `Referer` header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718930/conditional-routing-with-nginx-based-on-referer) but this would probably result in strange side effects at least with caching.

Comment: The Referer approach sounds good!  Why it would result in caching side effects?

Comment: It sounds more like a fun academic experiment to me. Anyways, when `http://xxx.yyy/logo.png` returns different content based on the `Referer` request header, the browser could cache it so you would see the wrong logo in `/app2/` when you visited `/app1` before. You could disable this behaviour by setting a [`no-cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) response header, but you would lose caching this way. Would not recommend.

Comment: what if you configure the reverse proxy to rewrite the paths in the incoming requests so that they match the paths expected by the website? I think this is simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

In your application use `window.location.href` and parse the first part of the URL and use it as base for your requestes.

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const appName = url.pathname.split('/').length > 2 ?  url.pathname.split('/')[1] : "";
const baseApiUrl = new URL(appName, url).toString();

fetch(baseApiUrl + '/api/getUsers')
     .then((res) = {})
     .catch((error) => { console.log(error)})
```